# Is possible to set an listener just for a part of a custom view?

Tags: android

I want to create a custom view (extends View) which contains an image and a text.

Is it possible to set an listener just for image if i use `canvas.drawBitmap(imageBitmap, ...)` method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your view just to show an image and a text, why not create a specific layout in your XML file and use `setContentView` to display the view?

If thats what you were looking for, I think that is the easiest approach. XML example coming soon.

Here is the contents of my personal view to display my main application, just to demonstrate how I can switch view's, your view would be different including a `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

**dblist.xml** inside of `res/layout` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#FFFFFF">
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:textColor="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This contents display my database results onto a `Spinner`

I can call that view by using:

```
setContentView(R.layout.dblist);
```

And if I want to return to my main layout, I can switch the view by calling

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

#### EDIT:

You can manipulate the view you are working with programmatically by using `findViewById` method. Let's use my *dblist.xml* file as an example, notice that my `ListView` has an id of `list`. So I would call:

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

With corresponds to that layout, so whenever I want to change anything to my XML file, I would reference `myList` use methods and callbacks to meet my needs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I want as my view to behave like a unique part of my application: I want to create a custom view (put inside of it a image and an text) and to use it with an list adapter. I can create this view(by example MyCustomView) by extending the RelativeLayout class and put on it an ImageView + TextView but every time when I call MyNewCustomView.invalidate() I think the myImageView.invalidate() and myTextView.invalidate() are called, right? If I have 1000 MyCustomView objects inside of my ListView I can't get the best speed!
 What do you think about this approach ? It is wrong?

Comment: Not 100% sure, all the layout's I have done have in the XML file itself, check here for some examples that might be helpful: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will take a look at the examples.. 

  All my application layout is made from code because I need to update it(adding/removing views). Please, can you give me an tip about how to update an layout what was created from an XML file? Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if you need anything else or further explanation.

Comment: No problem, come back if you need anything else